# Como melhorar o output do R

Tags: r

Existe algum pacote ou forma de deixar mais visual o output das regressões no R? Algo que deixe as informações mais organizadas, semelhante ao Stata e E-views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## **1ª Forma: Manual**

Eu normalmente obtenho o output do modelo de regressão que eu quero, transformo-o em um data frame, e para isso conto com a ajuda do pacote [`broom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html).

Em seguida, utilizo as funções de formatação de tabela, como `kable` [`kableExtra::kableExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html).

### Exemplo "na mão"

```
m1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)
sm1 <- summary(m1)
sm1$coefficients # Eu descobri que é nesse local que fica "guardado" os valores dos coeficientes depois de fazer str(summary(m1))
                   Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)       2.2513932  0.3697543  6.088890 9.568102e-09
Sepal.Width       0.8035609  0.1063390  7.556598 4.187340e-12
Speciesversicolor 1.4587431  0.1121079 13.011954 3.478232e-26
Speciesvirginica  1.9468166  0.1000150 19.465255 2.094475e-42
```

### Exemplo com o `broom`

```
broom::tidy(m1)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  term              estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)          2.25      0.370      6.09 9.57e- 9
2 Sepal.Width          0.804     0.106      7.56 4.19e-12
3 Speciesversicolor    1.46      0.112     13.0  3.48e-26
4 Speciesvirginica     1.95      0.100     19.5  2.09e-42
```

### Broom + Renomear as colunas

```
a <- broom::tidy(m1)
names(a) <- c("Covariáveis", "Estimativa", "Erro Padrão", "Estatística t", "Valor-p")
a
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Covariáveis       Estimativa `Erro Padrão` `Estatística t` `Valor-p`
  <chr>                  <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl>
1 (Intercept)            2.25          0.370            6.09  9.57e- 9
2 Sepal.Width            0.804         0.106            7.56  4.19e-12
3 Speciesversicolor      1.46          0.112           13.0   3.48e-26
4 Speciesvirginica       1.95          0.100           19.5   2.09e-42
```

Aí basta usar a função `kable` e `kable_extra` (quando necessário) para colocar num relatório:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E utilizar as opções extra de `kable` e `kableExtra` a vontade para personalizar.

## 2ª Forma: Automático

Quando eu digo "automático", quero dizer: Uma função irá coletar as principais informações do modelo e printar em uma tabela formatada.

### Via `stargazer`

O pacote [`stargazer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf) é muito bom e o mais "famoso":

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(m1, type = "html")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Via [sjPlot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/tab_model_estimates.html)

```
library(sjPlot)
tab_model(m1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Via [jtools](https://rdrr.io/cran/jtools/man/export_summs.html)

```
library(jtools)
export_summs(m1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Resumo

- Nos pacotes que trazem o resultado pronto, eu assumi que você está
  gerando um relatório no formato `html`, mas com algumas alterações,
  também é possível gerar para a maioria dessas funções um relatório
  `pdf`.
- Você ainda consegue fazer algumas variações dependendo do
  argumento de cada um deles, mas você fica limitado ao escopo dele e
  os tipos de modelo de regressão que eles aceitam, no entanto, é bem
  mais rápido.
- A vantagem de usar a forma `manual` é que é ilimitada, porém, demanda
  mais tempo.

Comment: Seria possível colocar um exemplo prático de como fazer isso?

Comment: Excelente. Esta é uma resposta que deveria ser muito bem votada pelos participantes do SO.

Comment: Obrigado @Marcus Nunes. Realmente, quando postei, achei que estava faltando os exemplos para a resposta ficar bem completinha. Espero que assim ajude!!

Comment: Certamente irá ajudar o AP e outros usuários que tiverem dúvidas parecidas.

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme, são ideias muito boas mesmo me ajudou bastante!!