# Como guardar os resultados de regressões feitas em loop em um data.frame

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando em um loop para gerar resultados de regressões com varias variáveis dependes. Usando esse script:

```
dataset <- as.data.table(mtcars)

t <- c("mpg", "vs")

for( coluna in t ){
  dataset$y <- dataset[, .SD,.SDcols = coluna]

#calculando a regressão
modtest <- lm( y ~ cyl + hp + wt, dataset)

lm <- broom::tidy(summary.lm(modtest))

}
```

Mas não estou conseguindo guardar todos esses resultados do loop empilhados em um único `data.frame`.
Como posso fazer para armazenar todos os resultados da regressão em um único `data.frame` empilhados?

Comment: Que resultados quer guardar, os coeficientes, os erros padrão, etc?

Comment: Exato Rui. Quero guarda todos resultados da regressão

Comment: [Relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376989/como-melhorar-o-output-do-r).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em vez de um ciclo `for`, use um ciclo `lapply`, guarde os resultados das regressões numa lista (`res_list`) e depois um pipe cria um data.frame.

```r
library(data.table)
# library(dplyr)
# library(broom)
# library(purrr)

dataset <- as.data.table(mtcars)

tt <- c("mpg", "vs")

res_list <- lapply(tt, \(coluna) {
  dataset$y <- dataset[, .SD, .SDcols = coluna]
  #calculando a regressão
  lm(y ~ cyl + hp + wt, dataset)
})

res_list |>
  purrr::map(summary) |>
  purrr::map(broom::tidy) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept) 38.8       1.79       21.7   4.80e-19
#> 2 cyl         -0.942     0.551      -1.71  9.85e- 2
#> 3 hp          -0.0180    0.0119     -1.52  1.40e- 1
#> 4 wt          -3.17      0.741      -4.28  1.99e- 4
#> 5 (Intercept)  1.73      0.213       8.14  7.37e- 9
#> 6 cyl         -0.237     0.0656     -3.61  1.19e- 3
#> 7 hp          -0.00119   0.00141    -0.841 4.08e- 1
#> 8 wt           0.107     0.0882      1.22  2.34e- 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: [Rui Barradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/82237/rui-barradas) Estou migrando de dataframe (dplyr) para `data.table`. Vi que você usou `.SD` e `.SDcols`. Já havia visto o uso de `.N` e `.I` em alguma página perdida no Google. Você indica algum lugar onde eu possa aprender mais sobre `data.table`?

Comment: @PauloMarques Veja a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)  e `help(".SD")`.

Comment: Acrescentei lm <- para que se torna-se um dataset como eu queria

lm <- res_list |>
  purrr::map(summary) |>
  purrr::map(broom::tidy) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()

Answer (score -2):

Sugestão com menos pacotes, e mais genérica(Editado)

```
  teste <- function(val,dt){
    x<-data.frame(
        summary(
            lm(as.formula(paste0(val,"~cyl+hp+wt")), dt)
        )$coefficients
    )
    x["term"] <- rownames(x)
    rownames(x)<-NULL
    x["y"]<-rep(val, nrow(x))
    return(x)
}

do.call("rbind", lapply(c("mpg", "vs"), teste, mtcars))
```

---

Correções, percebi que não estava produzindo a mesma saída. Agora corrigido. a ordem e título das colunas podem diferir mas o resultado é o mesmo.